# How to select max Id from nested select?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to select max Id from nested select.

Here is the my query:

```
select max(Id) from (SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable]) t
```

This *select* should return 100, but it actually returns max id of *MyTable*.

P.S. *MyTable* contains 100 000 records, so query returns 100 000.

**Here is an Example:**

*returns 100 (It's ok)*

```
SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable]
```

*returns 100 000, but I want to select max id of "SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable]"*

```
select max(Id) from (SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable]) t
```

*returns 100 000, but I want to select max id of "SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable] where Id > 100"*

```
select max(Id) from (SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable] where Id > 100) t
```

Comment: Why do you think it should return 100?  You are asking for the maximum Id out of the 100 records you selected.  You need `count()` if you want to count the number of rows.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is? The sub select returns the top 100 IDs. You then grab the max ID from there. 

If you need to see 100 (which should be the max id if you sort MyTable by ID and it has a chain of uninterrupted id-numbers), add `ORDER BY ID ASC` in the subquery

Comment: No I want max id of nested select. Not count.

Comment: What do you want to return? The max(ID) of all the table? The max(id) of the lowest 100 IDs? The 100 lowest IDs? The highest 100 IDs?

Comment: `TOP` without `ORDER BY` should be forbidden, it's meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries with `TOP` but without `ORDER BY`, like yours:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    Id 
FROM tableX ;
```

**do not return consistent results.** The above means *"show me 100 IDs, I don't care which, from the millions there are in the table"*. The DBMS is free to return any 100 it chooses, any time you run the query. It can even choose to send you back the same 100 for the first 2 years, then suddenly change its mind and return some other 100 of them.

In fact, that's what you see, when it is used a subquery, the optimizer transforms the query **"give me the max of any 100 IDs"** to ***"give me the max of all the IDs of the table"***

---

Change that query to (you can use any `ORDER BY` of your choice):

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    Id 
FROM tableX 
  ORDER BY Id ;
```

on its own and where it is used as a subquery and you will have consistent behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I think nested query just return top 100 rows and id 100000 is one of them. Try this

```
select max(Id) from (SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable] order by Id asc) t
```

Comment: No "SELECT TOP 100 Id FROM [MyTable]" returns 100